# Using Acronis True Image with Virtual Machines

Tags: virtualization, acronis

I would like to create a scheduled cloning of a hard disk with Acronis.

There will be multiple virtual machines running off the hard disk being cloned (using Xen).

Does the virtualisation have any implications for the backup, or will everything proceed as normal, regardless of what is on the disk to be copied?

Furthermore, in this scenario, how should I install Acronis? (on the hypervisor?), or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want [Acronis TrueImage Virtual Edition](http://www.acronis.com/enterprise/products/ATIVE/).  It sounds like the newer product is called [Acronis Backup & Recovery](http://www.acronis.com/backup-recovery/advanced-server-virtual/).  Here's an additional article: http://kb.acronis.com/content/2311

Comment: thanks very much - please up vote question to give me enough rep to upvote your answer. thanks again

Comment: answer now upvoted